# GON - not getting value in js.erb + Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, gon

Gem File

```
gem 'gon'
```

This is my application.html.erb File.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Title</title>
    <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
    <%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>           
  </head>
  <body>
    ....
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, On many pages(Index) I delete my records with ajax. like

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></i>".html_safe, section_path(sec_content, type: params[:type]), class: 'pull-right', title: 'Delete Section', data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner'></i>".html_safe, confirm: 'Are you sure want to delete ?'}, method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

In Controller, Destroy action code.

```
def destroy
  gon.test_id = 1
  section.destroy if section.present?      
end
```

Now, It's goes to destroy.js.erb file

```
console.log(gon)
alert(gon.test_id)
$("#section_<%= params[:id] %>").remove();
```

Now, the console.log nothing to display and alert will comes but it display me 'undefine'

Can anyone help me what's wrong in above code so I can use gon in js.erb files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i face the same problem with gon , what i do is i assign the value in session variable like `session[:test] = 1` and then assign the session to gon `gon.test_id = session[:test]` and it works fine

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(<%= gon %>)` ?

Comment: @Зелёный - Getting error - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `gon' for #<#<Class:0xb0dd0b5c>:0xb13598f8>):

Comment: did this ever get resolved?  I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

mark `require 'gon'` in controller & try.

Comment: Still getting same error. the console.log nothing to display and alert will comes but it display me 'undefine'

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you have to use [gon watch](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch) to use Gon with Ajax.

---

You also should do

```
<%= Gon::Base.render_data(init: true) %>

# instead of 
# <%= Gon::Base.render_data %>
# <%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
```

Comment: If I follow the instructions for gon.watch, everything works fine. Can you show me how you implemented gon.watch?